# Exceptions and reboots when creating anchors in ARCore

Tags: java, android, arcore

I am experimenting with an Android codebase originally derived from the ARCore sample application (Java). Instead of attaching anchors to a plane, I store the camera pose on specific occasions and later attach anchors based on that stored pose but with some position offset. This usually works fine but occasionally I get one of the following problems:

1. Exception without further detail when I try to create the anchor,
   with a prior log entry of: *query_timestamp_s is not in the valid range (may be just a coincidence)*
2. Exception without further detail when I try to create the anchor,
    with a prior cryptic log message saying: *Could not create PoseNode*
3. The phone freezes for about three seconds and then reboots (Google
   Pixel 2)

Would appreciate any ideas about deeper trouble-shooting as well as hearing whether anyone else had similar problems.

**Edited with a possible solution:** I received input from Google that the problem may have been caused by in some cases re-using Pose objects between frames (as opposed to always attaching anchors and retrieving a new pose for comparison). I was vaguely aware of this restriction but seemed to have missed a few places. Initial investigation seemed to support this as the probable cause as I couldn't quickly re-produce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because of

> As ARCore's understanding of the environment changes, it adjusts its
>   model of the world to keep things consistent. When this happens, the
>   numerical location (coordinates) of the camera and Anchors can change
>   significantly to maintain appropriate relative positions of the
>   physical locations they represent.

as the docs [state](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Pose). Maybe recording and calculating the exact path your camera has moved (direction in meters) since your *initial position*. When you need a previous position, just calculate the past position with the current one and your recorded path.